# Reading mixed numeric and text columns with read_excel() from the readxl package

Tags: r, readxl

I'm trying to ingest a large collection of legacy Excel 97-2003 files (`.xls`) using `read_excel()` from the `readxl` package. One of the columns in these files is an alphanumeric code with some blanks (e.g., `"", "1", "1A", "1B", "2", "3", "3A"`, etc.). In the original Excel file, the cells in this column which include only numbers have a `TYPE()` of `1` while the cells which include letters and the blank cells have a `TYPE()` of `2`.

When I read in the file using `read_excel()`, the corresponding column in the data frame is automagically converted to type `chr` (which is what I want), but the elements that contain only numbers end up being coded as decimals, so I end up with `"", "1.000000", "1A", "1B", "2.000000", "3.000000", "3A"`, etc. Forcing conversion to text with `read_excel(..., coltypes = c(...,"text",...)` doesn't seem to make any difference.

I can easily fix the resulting data frame with a little `regex` fiddling, but is there a way to avoid this in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried saving the file as `xlsx` if there is no risk of data loss?

Comment: Good point. I should have said that this is a _large_ number of files, so any solution that requires me to go into each Excel file individually is not so useful.

Comment: If one column has both numeric and character types, then R will convert it into character type. In R, atomic vectors must have only one type. Otherwise, forced typecasting will occur (Eg: all numerics will be type casted to character). I suspect, this has anything to do with the package you mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Satish: Yes. Forcing to `chr` type is fine. In fact, that's what I want. I just don't want to end up with all of those trailing zeroes.

Comment: If you can install the xlsx package and get it to run without any rJava trouble, then you could try its read.xlsx function. Perhaps that can import your data properly. This issue is perhaps linked to the implementation of the reader function in the readxl package. You may go ahead and open an issue [here](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/issues).